# Handle a keyboard that produces only keypress instead of keydown/keyup events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I have a weird situation where a specialty PC keyboard produces strange codes in JavaScript when pressing the number keys.

Using this site (http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html), I found that the keyboard produces this when pressing the number 4:

```
keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
keydown  keyCode=101 (e)   which=101 (e)   charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=101 (e)   which=101 (e)   charCode=0        
keydown  keyCode=98  (b)   which=98  (b)   charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=98  (b)   which=98  (b)   charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=52  (4)   which=52  (4)   charCode=52  (4)
```

A regular keyboard produces this:

```
keydown  keyCode=52  (4)   which=52  (4)   charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=52  (4)   which=52  (4)   charCode=52  (4)  
keyup    keyCode=52  (4)   which=52  (4)   charCode=0
```

So basically, this strange device holds the ALT key, adds two other characters, lets go of the ALT key, and THEN fires ONLY the keypress event for the actual key while ignoring keydown and keyup completely.

I can filter out the first part with `event.altKey` no problem, but it's the rest that is causing issues.

The problem is that my code was written to do one thing on keydown and another on keyup, and adding keypress only for this one keyboard is messing up everything...

I doubt there's a solution for this, and we probably just won't support this ... weird piece of hardware, but just in case:

Any ideas on how to detect if a keyboard creates only keypress (after filtering out the other `event.altKey` events before that)?

I tried having a global variable that contains the current event code and that is reset both on keypress and keyup and otherwise receives the current keycode, but I just can't get this to work...

Here's my code:

```
<input type="text" name="entry" id="entry" onkeyup="Entry('up', this, event);" onkeydown="Entry('down', this, event);" />
```

Yes, all keyboard events are supposed to be passed through into the text field, so no `return` needed here.
And the JavaScript:

```
function Entry(dir, field, evt)
{
    // filter out Num Lock, Alt and Alt Pressed
    if (evt.keyCode == 144 || evt.keyCode == 18 || evt.altKey)
        return false;

    if (dir == 'up')  // keyup
    {
        if (field.value.length > 0) 
        { 
            if (evt.keyCode == 13) // Enter pressed
            {
                EnterUser();  // if more entries are found with FindUser(), select the first one, otherwise empty the screen
            }
            else 
            {
                FindUser();  // start ajax that checks field content vs database
            }
        }
    }
    else  // keydown
    {
        if (!field.disabled)
        {
            EmptyScreen();  // if the text field is disabled because a dialog box is in front, empty the screen.
        }
    }
}
```

The trick, of course, is to support this weird keyboard while not breaking stuff for other keyboards and barcode scanners that are currently working.

Chance are that we'll have to tell the customer "Sorry, get yourself a proper keyboard" or something, but it's bugging me :-)

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

PS: I have jQuery on that site, so if there's any good ideas that use that, I'd be game, too.

Comment: Wild guess: One thing you could try is to use `addEventListener()` instead to hook up your event handler in case the `event` object passed to that callback is somehow different/better than the one you're getting by using `onkeyup` in the HTML.

Comment: You've explained what that keyboard does, but do you know _why_ it does it? Is it a programmable keyboard designed for accessibility for people with disabilities or something? (If so it may have a "normal" mode.)

Comment: It's some form of cashier or POS keyboard as far as I know. I'm hoping it can be reprogrammed to just not do this :-)  (going home for today, will continue replying tomorrow, thanks!)

Comment: This behavior might change depending on which javascript engine you're running... could be worth trying a different browser, if that's an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't predict what browser our clients might use... So far, it's looking like we're stuck with not supporting this weird keyboard. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled on this problem as well. A barcode scanner configured to send text in alt codes does this too.

There is an easy solution at least for Chrome (I haven't checked firefox), but both IE, and Edge requires a different approach, because those browsers fail to raise `KeyUp` event for the **Alt** key, which is an essential part to the solution.

Google chrome registers the **Alt** `keyUp` event, and event translates the "alt-code". All you need to do is to skip keys while the **Alt** key is being held and check the `key` property when on the ***Alt*** `KeyUp` event:

[image]

For IE and Edge browsers, you need to save characters while the alt key is held, convert them to a number and use `String.fromCharCode(057)` to get "9", the problem is it is hard to detect when to convert, because there are no `KeyUp` event for **Alt** button after "alt-code".

The solution I chose and that works with every browser (I think), was to focus a hidden input field on `KeyDown`event for **Alt** key, and read its contents after they change, because inputs correctly handle the "Alt codes"

This might be late answer but may be of some use to other people.